# Beautiful soup is giving other value's than the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[image]

Beautiful soup is giving another value than is presented on the website.

the site is only updating every one or two minutes.

What am I doing wrong?

here is the code I 'am using:`enter code here

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
while 1<=2:
      url1= 'https://www.ig.com/nl/forex/markten-forex/eur-usd'
      response = requests.get(url1)
      time.sleep(1)
      price = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser').findAll('div' {'class':'price-ticket__values'})[0].find('div').text
      print(price)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the text of your question, not as a link or image

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. But you don't have a solution?

Comment: Please give an example of the output from your code (which you say is “wrong”) and the html and the value displayed on the website (Which you say is “right”) in a browser at the same time.

Comment: Thanks you for the response Barney, the output of the code is the first second the same as the output as the website for example (1.0853). But afther the first value the output of the code keeps giving (1,0853) while the value displayed on the website is changing (1.0851), (1,0858) etc. But after 2 minuts the output of the code is updating to the value on the website and gives an other 2 minutes the same value.